# How to retrieve the value of an Http Request parameter into a Servlet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, httprequest

I am absolutly new in J2EE and this if my first time that I implement an **HttpServlet**

In my **web.xml** file I have putted the following configuration:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>salwf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>it.sistinf.ediweb.monitor.servlets.Salwf</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>salwf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/salwf.do/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So this servlet is performed for the **/salwf.do/*** pattern into the HTTP REQUEST.

Into the **service()** method of my servlet I found something like it:

```
String service = req.getParameter("serv");
```

So what exactly do this line? I think that it retrieve the value of a GET paramether named **serv** inside the HTTP Request.

So for example if in my browser I put something like it:

```
http://localhost:7001/salwf.do/myPage?serv=1
```

it is retrieved the "1" value of the **serv** parameter?

Is it correct or am I missing something?

Tnx

Comment: All the fields(in jsp) information and URL fields will be transfered and made available with request object as 'parameter' and if any other information set explicitly, then this will be available as 'attribute'.

Comment: Totally correct; works also for POST of form inputs. `null` when no such parameter. Use `string[] req.getParameterValues("arr")` for URLs `...?arr=2&sarr=3&arr=5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your corrrect that if you have tthe GET parameter `?serv=1` that `req.getParameter("serv")` will return the value of the parameter (in this case `1`) as a String.

So if you do what you have, `String service = req.getParameter("serv");` and the request has a GET parameter that looks like this `?serv=1` then the value of `service` is now `"1"`.

In your case the `<servlet-mapping>` in `web.xml` is incorrect. You should remove the `/*` after `/sawlf.do`

Looks like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>salwf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/salwf.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then if you want to send a request to the servlet the url should look like this:
`http://localhost:7001/salwf.do?serv=1`